# Showing null output in Node.js when using POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using POSTMAN to test me API calls with Node.Js.When I am sending POST request from POSTMAN to Node server it is showing null response in console.log().

```
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 var app = express();
 var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

 router.get('/',(req,res) => {

     console.log("Name:" +req.body.name);
     res.end();
 });

 app.listen(port,(req,res) =>{

     console.log("Server is running at:" +port);
  });
```

Now, I am sending POSTMAN request at URL = localhost:3000/ and data is

```
 Key: name and Value: John
```

In console it is showing error like

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: And what encoding have you set Postman to send the data in?

Comment: I am newbie and using POSTMAN first time so dont know how to set encoding.

Comment: Use `console.log(req.body)`, what is result?

Comment: Pranav Singh, I have tried your method but showing .TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Comment: I am just asking what is coming inside `req.body`. Error is telling there is no property of `name` inside `req.body`. Just log `req.body` without `name` you will know what you are getting in actual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your method to POST like this:

```
router.post('/',(req,res) => {

  console.log("Name:" +req.body.name);
  res.end();
});
```

Also you need to make a post throw POSTMAN with this options :
[image]

And you should have your result :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean Pranav?

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer without any reason, I also got many random downvotes for helpful answers without stating reason for downvote. Anyway I upvoted so that you won't get hit for helping

Comment: Ha i see thank you very much , anyway i dont see a point on down votes anyway since ppl that answer here and if they take some off their time to do it, its because want to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Tiago and Pranav, got it fixed...But one thing when im saving data to MongoDB i want response from server that data has been saved. For that  i am using something like this:     mongo.con.db("Tiffino_db").collection("Places").insertOne(obJ,(err,res) => {

            if(err){

              console.log("Error:" +err);
            }
            else{

                 res.send("Data has been saved");
            }

          });     But this in my console it is showing res.send() is not  function but data has been saved successfully.

Comment: You can send a `res.status(200).json({message: 'You saved successfull'})` something like this. Also if my answer fixed your issue please accept the answer so ppl know its done :)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the request in the express framework as a get:
 router.get

and you said you are sending a POST. 
Change one thing or the other

Comment: I have change request type to POST in express framework and sending POST request from POSTMAN as well but again the same error is showing.

Comment: Try to send the post with header Content-Type: application/json
and the body like this:  { "name": "John" }